# Creating torrent files dynamic using bash

Tags: bash, shell

I'm trying create .torrent files using create-torrent.
I have a lot of .mp4 files inside many folders and subfolders.

Here is my command line:

```
find . -type f -name "*.mp4" -exec bash -c 'create-torrent {} --urlList "http://127.0.0.1/test/{}" -o ${1%.mp4}.torrent' sh {}  \; -print
```

This will create a .torrent for each .mp4 file inside folders and subfolders, this command above is working!

But, I must use "urlList" as webseed. Using webseed, I need the http link ponting to .mp4 file, so this is the reason to hide /var/www/

Webseed definition: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BitTorrent#Web_seeding

So, I need the real path of the current .mp4 file.

For example, if I have a .mp4 file on this folder: **/var/www/teste/folder1/video.mp4**, I must have this following command line:

```
find . -type f -name "*.mp4" -exec bash -c 'create-torrent {} --urlList "http://127.0.0.1/teste/folder/video.mp4/{}" -o ${1%.mp4}.torrent' sh {}  \; -print
```

Note that I'm not using **/var/www/**

I know a command on linux that shows me the path of the file: **readlink -f {name}**

But this command returns with **/var/www/**

How can I dynamic insert the current directory of the file excluding **/var/www/** on this command  below?

```
find . -type f -name "*.mp4" -exec bash -c 'create-torrent {} --urlList "http://127.0.0.1/{REAL_PATH_WITHOUT_VARWWW}/{}" -o ${1%.mp4}.torrent' sh {}  \; -print
```

I tried so much fix this by myself but I failed
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

An easy fix for the `readlink` command would be:

```
readlink -f <your_mp4_file> | awk -F '/var/www' '{print $2}'
```

Take /var/www as a delimiter, and print the second column (everything else) .

Now, example for your case using the same awk command, something like this:

```
# find /var/www/html/ -type f | awk -F '/var/www' '{print $2}'
/html/index.html
/html/something.html  

# for path in $(find /var/www/html/ -type f | awk -F '/var/www' '{print $2}'); do echo "do something with this -> $path"; done
do something with this -> /html/index.html
do something with this -> /html/something.html
```

**Solution** (with your command):

```
for mp4 in $(find . -type f -name "*.mp4" | awk -F '.*/var/www' '{print $2}'); do bash -c "create-torrent $mp4 --urlList 'http://127.0.0.1/$mp4/{}' -o ${1%.mp4}.torrent" sh {}  \; -print; done
```

P.S - I don't know why you're explicitly starting new bash session. If you don't explicitly have a requirement for doing it like that (i.e executing the command on remote servers), you can do:

```
for mp4 in $(find . -type f -name "*.mp4" | awk -F '.*/var/www' '{print $2}'); do create-torrent $mp4 --urlList "http://127.0.0.1/$mp4/{} -o ${1%.mp4}.torrent; done
```

Comment: Hello, I'm getting this error: `line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `file'` using `for mp4 file in $(find . -type f -name "*.mp4" | awk -F '.*/var/www' '{print $2}'); do bash -c "create-torrent {} --urlList 'http://127.0.0.1/$mp4/{}' -o ${1%.mp4}.torrent" sh {}  \; -print; done`

Comment: I used bash to replace file extension!

Comment: Replacing `for mp4 file in` to `for mp4 in` and `{print $2}` to `{print $1}` make the script works without syntax errors, but I'm getting `Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '{}'` and this make sense since {} is from find command and the find command is only being used to search file folder and strip /var/www/. How can we solve this?

Comment: Sorry, edited the answer. Have you tried replacing {} with $mp4 ?